# react-native run-ios won't work after changing projects name

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, debugging, react-native

I decided to change the name of my `React Native` project by first changing it in the main directory to name it "AppName" by getting rid of its previous name.

I also changed all the folders names inside my `ios` into `AppName` and got rid of its previous name.

Even inside the `index.ios.js`, I got rid of its previous name.

However, whenever I run `react-native run-ios`, I get the following error:

```
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app
An error was encountered processing the command 
(domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier 
build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

Why am I getting this error?  I know it has something to do with changing the name of my project.

Comment: Edit your bundle identifier too. It has to have the same name as your project: `com.myCompany.projectName`.

Answer (score 0):

to rename `react native` project you should use [react-native-rename](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZ45-0gK3WAhUEVhQKHcgDBfkQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.npmjs.com%2Fpackage%2Freact-native-rename&usg=AFQjCNF5TRevH8LpTa4KWlyZqz0o1bVQZQ)
because manual rename will break your project